# How to enforce authorization policies across multiple applications?

Tags: web-services, authorization, distributed, access-control

## Background

I have a backoffice that manages information from various sources. Part of the information is in a database that the backoffice can access directly, and part of it is managed by accessing web services. Such services usually provides CRUD operations plus paged searches.

There is an access control system that determines what actions a user is allowed to perform. The decision of whether the user can perform some action is defined by authorization rules that depend on the underlying data model. E.g. there is a rule that allows a user to edit a resource if she is the owner of that resource, where the owner is a column in the resources table. There are other rules such as "a user can edit a resource if that resource belongs to an organization and the user is a member of that organization". 
This approach works well when the domain model is directly available to the access control system. Its main advantage is that it avoids replicating information that is already present in the domain model.

When the data to be manipulated comes from a Web service, this approach starts causing problems. I can see various approaches that I will discuss below.

### Implementing the access control in the service

This approach seems natural, because otherwise someone could bypass access control by calling the service directly. The problem is that **the backoffice has no way to know what actions are available to the user on a particular entity**. Because of that, it is not possible to disable options that are unavailable to the user, such as an "edit" button.

One could add additional operations to the service to retrieve the authorized actions on a particular entity, but it seems that we would be handling multiple responsibilities to the service.

### Implementing the access control in the backoffice

Assuming that the service trusts the backoffice application, one could decide to implement the access control in the backoffice. This seems to solve the issue of knowing which actions are available to the user. The main issue with this approach is that **it is no longer possible to perform paged searches** because the service will now return every entity that matches, instead of entities that match and that the user is also authorized to see.

### Implementing a centralized access control service

If access control was centralized in a single service, everybody would be able to use it to consult access rights on specific entities. However, we would **lose the ability to use the domain model to implement the access control rules**. There is also a performance issue with this approach, because in order to return lists of search results that contain only the authorized results, there is no way to filter the database query with the access control rules. One has to **perform the filtering in memory after retrieving all of the search results**.

### Conclusion

I am now stuck because none of the above solutions is satisfactory. What other approaches can be used to solve this problem? Are there ways to work around the limitations of the approaches I proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One could add additional operations to the service to retrieve the
>   authorized actions on a particular entity, but it seems that we would
>   be handling multiple responsibilities to the service.

Not really. Return a flags field/property from the web service for each record/object that can then be used to pretty up the UI based on what the user can do. The flags are based off the same information that is used for access control that the service is accessing anyway. This also makes the service able to support a browser based AJAX access method and skip the backoffice part in the future for added flexibility.

Comment: That makes sense. I have weighted other alternatives and this one seems to be the only one that has no real drawback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish between the components of your access control system and implement each where it makes sense.

Access to specific search results in a list should be implemented by the service that reads the results, and the user interface never needs to know about the results the user doesn't have access to. If the user may or may not edit or interact in other ways with data the user is allowed to see, the service should return that data with flags indicating what the user may do, and the user interface should reflect those flags. Service implementing those interactions should **not** trust the user interface, it should validate the user has access when the service is called. You may have to implement the access control logic in multiple database queries.

Access to general functionality the user may or may not have access to independant of data should again be controlled by the service implementing that functionality. That service should compute access through a module that is also exposed as a service so that the UI can respect the access rules and not try to call services the user does not have access to.

Answer (score 1):

I understand my response is very late - 3 years late. It's worth shedding some new light on an age-old problem. Back in 2011, [access-control](/questions/tagged/access-control) was not as mature as it is today. In particular, there is a new model, [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) along with a standard implementation, [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) which make centralized authorization possible.

In the OP's question, the OP writes the following re centralized access control:

> ### Implementing a centralized access control service
>
> If access control was centralized in a single service, everybody would be able to use it to consult access rights on specific entities. However, we would **lose the ability to use the domain model to implement the access control rules**. There is also a performance issue with this approach, because in order to return lists of search results that contain only the authorized results, there is no way to filter the database query with the access control rules. One has to **perform the filtering in memory after retrieving all of the search results**.

The drawbacks that the OP mentions may have been true in a home-grown access control system, in RBAC, or in ACL. But they are no longer true in [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) and [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml). Let's take them one by one.

### The ability to use the domain model to implement the access control rules

With attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)) and the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)), it is possible to use the domain model and its properties (or attributes) to write access control policies. For instance, if the use case is that of a doctor wishing to view medical records, the domain model would define the `Doctor` entity with its properties (location, unit, and so on) as well as the `Medical Record` entity. A rule in XACML could look as follows:

- A user with the role==doctor can do the action==view on an object of type==medical record if and only if the doctor.location==medicalRecord.location.
- A user with the role==doctor can do the action==edit on an object of type==medical record if and only if the doctor.id==medicalRecord.assignedDoctor.id

One of the key benefits of XACML is precisely to mirror closely the business logic and the domain model of your applications.

### Performance issue - the ability to filter items from a db

In the past, it was indeed impossible to create filter expressions. This meant that, as the OP points out, one would have to retrieve all the data first and then filter the data. That would be an expensive task. Now, with XACML, it is possible to achieve reverse querying. The ability to run a reverse query is to create a question of the type *"What medical record can Alice view?"* instead of the traditional binary question *"Can Alice view medical records #123?"*.
The response of a reverse query is a filter condition which can be converted into a SQL statement, for instance in this scenario `SELECT id FROM medicalRecords WHERE location=Chicago` assuming of course that the doctor is based in Chicago.

## What does the architecture look like?

One of the key benefits of a centralized access control service (also known as externalized authorization) is that you can apply the same consistent authorization logic to your presentation tier, business tier, APIs, web services, and even databases.

[image: The XACML any-depth architecture according to Axiomatics]